# Making my search bar responsive like Google's with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to make the search bar move to the top when it is clicked on, to move beside the burger just like the way Google's search bar responds, and the lan not appearing on the screen when this happens. Please help.

My HTML code:

```css
    body{
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
    }

    p, input, textarea{
 font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    }

    /****************
    SECTION
    *****************/
    a{
 color: #fa694e;
    }


    /*************
    this controls the nav bar
    *************/
    .menu-toggle{
 position: absolute;
 left: 15px; 
 top: 15px;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #fff;
    }

    .menu{
 width: 300px;
 display: block;
 background: #333;/* controls the color of the nav bar*/
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left:-300px; 
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 text-align: center;
 transition: left 0.4s;
    }

    .menu.nav-expanded{
 left: 0; 
    }

    .menu .close{
 color: #fff;
 margin-right: 10px;
 margin-top:10px;
    }

    .menu h3{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
    }


    .menu .nav{
 padding: 0;
    }

    .menu .nav > li > a{
 color: #fff;
    }

    .menu .nav > li > a:hover,
    .menu .nav > li > a:focus{
 background: transparent;
 color: #0EBFE9;
    }

    
    /***
    navbar ending
    ***/



    .jumbotron{
 text-align: center;
 position: fixed; 
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-size: cover;
 color: #fff;
 min-height: 400px;
    }

    .jumbotron .mask{
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: #fff;
 opacity: 0.5;
    }

    .jumbotron p{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px
    }

    .jumbotron .container{
 margin-top: 10%;
    }

    .jumbotron h1{
 text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .header-info{
 position: relative;
    }


    .log {
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s, color 0.4s;
 transition: border-color 0.4s, color 0.4s;
 width: 100px;
    } 

    .button{
 background: #0EBFE9;
 border-width: 2px;
 color: #fff;
 border-color: #0EBFE9;
    }

    .one{
 padding: 10px 41px;
    }

    .two{
 padding: 10px 34px;
    }

    .three{
 padding: 10px 41px;
    }

    .menu h5 {
 padding-bottom: 15px
    }

    .btn{
 position: absolute;
 right: 15px;
 -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 padding: 8px 22px;
 border-radius: 0;
 -webkit-transition: border-color 0.4s, color 0.4s;
 transition: border-color 0.4s, color 0.4s;
    }

    .btn-primary{
 background: #0EBFE9;
 border-width: 2px;
 color: #fff;
 border-color: #0EBFE9;
    }

    .btn-primary:focus{
 background: ##0EBFE9;
 color: #fff;
 border-color: #0EBFE9;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 768px){

 .jumbotron h1,
 .jumbotron .h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
 }
 h4{
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
 }
    }


    /***************************************
    search bar
    ***************************************/
    input{
    border: none;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 60%;
  min-width: 300px;
    border:1px solid #eaeaea;
    outline:none;
  color: black;
    }
    input:hover{
    border-color: #a0a0a0 #b9b9b9 #b9b9b9 #b9b9b9;
    }

    input:focus{
    border-color:#4d90fe;
    }

    
    .fa-map-marker {
 color: green;
    }

    .fa-bars {
 color: green;
    }


    .lan{
 color: green;
    }

    .words {
 color: #333
    }

    /*footer*/
    footer{
 position: absolute;
 padding: 0;
 bottom: 0pt;
 text-align: left;
    }

    footer > ul > li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 10px;
    }

    h4{
 color: black;
 font-size: 13px;
    }

    footer > ul > li > h4 > a {
 color: black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en-us">
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>lan</title>

 <!-- Load fonts -->
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' 
    rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora' rel='stylesheet' 
    type='text/css'>

 <!-- Load css styles -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />

    </head>
    <body>
 <div class="jumbotron home home-fullscreen" id="home">
 <div class="mask"></div>

 <a href="" class="menu-toggle" id="nav-expander"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    </a>
 <!-- Offsite navigation -->
 <nav class="menu">
 <a href="#" class="close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
 <h5><a data-scroll href="login.html" class="log button one">log in</a></h5>
 <h5><a data-scroll href="signup.html" class="log button two">sign up</a>
    </h5>
 <ul class="nav">

 </ul>
 </nav>

 <!-- add searches -->
 <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">add searches</a>
 <!-- ending -->

 <div class="container">
 <div class="header-info">
 <h1><span class="space">lan</span><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-
    hidden="true"></i></h1>
 
    <p><span class= "words">finding stuffs
 </span></p>
 <!-- making a search bar -->
 <div class="form-group">
 <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="lan searches?" />
 </div>
    </div>
 </div>

 <!-- Footer start -->
  <footer class="foot">
  <ul>
   <li><h4>&copy; lankey</h4></li>
   <li> <h4> <a href=""> About </a> </h4> </li>
   <li> <h4> <a href=""> Contact </a> </h4> </li>
   <li> <h4> <a href=""> Help </a> </h4> </li>
   </ul>
   </footer>
   <!-- Footer end  -->
 </div>



 <!-- Contact section start -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

 <!-- Load Booststrap -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/smooth-scroll.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?
    sensor=false"></script>

 <!-- Load custom js for theme -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What is not working about it?

Comment: i wanted to know how i can make the search bar move to the top of the page when i click on it, like how google's search bar reacts.